# Can I stream specific Azure website custom log files with the Azure command line tools?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cli, azure-xplat-cli

The Azure CLI can stream all logs (both native and custom - basically anything under `\Home\LogFiles\`)for an Azure App Service:

```
azure site log tail sitename
```

And you can apply a filter to the tail:

```
azure site log tail sitename --filter
```

But there appears to be no way to stream a specific, custom log file, e.g. `\Home\LogFiles\MyCustomLog.log` or `\Home\LogFiles\MyLogs\MyCustomLog.log`.

The `azure site log tail` command has a `--path` option, where `--path` is a directory path under `\Home\LogFiles\`, but it streams *all* logs in that directory.

Is there a way to stream just specific custom log files?  If not, I can certainly make one subdirectory per-custom log file and use the `--path` option that way.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to stream just specific custom log files? If not, I can certainly make one subdirectory per-custom log file and use the --path option that way.

In my opinion, we could not directly stream a specific custom log file via Azure CLI. Currently, we use the following command to [stream the log from File System](https://github.com/Azure/azure-xplat-cli/wiki/Web-Site-Diagnostics),

`azure site log tail [options] [name]`

and it supports only these two options,

- -p, --path: the log path under LogFiles folder
- -f, --filter: filter matching line

it just enable us to use **-f** “xxx” to filter and stream the specific log containing "xxx" in the message from specified folder. So if you’d like to steam a specific custom log file, as you said, you could create subfolder for each custom log file. Besides, you could create your own rule while writing log, for example, you could append “MyCustomLog” as prefix before log message when you write custom log. And then you could use **-f** to filter the specific log message containing the prefix.

Comment: Thank you.  It appears we've come to the same conclusion.  Perhaps you should update your answer by starting it with something like "It is not possible directly stream a specific custom log file.  Some alternative mechanisms are...", and then I will mark it as accepted.